# Is it possible to find matrix $A$ and matrix $B$ if you know $AB$ and $BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Assuming that matrix $A$ & $B$ are both square and invertible, is there a reliable way to separate out matrix $A$ and $B$ from $AB$ and $BA$?
For example, if I want to find matrix $A$ and matrix $B$:
$$
AB =  
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -4 &  -1 \\ 
5 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-5 & -1 & -1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
BA =
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 4 &  1 \\ 
-4 & 1 & -5 \\ 
-1 & 1 & -2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How would would I find $A$ and $B$?

(for the record, these specific matrices were arbitrarily made with a calculator and are only here for the sake of example, so:)
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &  -1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-2 & -1 & -1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &  -1 \\ 
2 & -2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: You can't even do this for $1\times1$ matrices. If you know $ab=ba=6$, can you work out $a$ and $b$?

Comment: As an exanple, suppose $AB=BA=I$.

Comment: The matrices $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ in your example aren't *invertible*, as specified in your original question.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
If $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are two square matrices, then there exist invertible square matrices $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ satisfying the equations
\begin{align}
AB&=K_1\label{e1}\tag{1}\\
BA&=K_2\label{e2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
if and only if $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity), and both invertible.

If $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are invertible matrices satisfying equations (\ref{e1}) and (\ref{e2}), then
$$
A=K_1B^{-1}=B^{-1}K_2\ ,
$$
from which it follows that $\ K_1=B^{-1}K_2B\ $—that is, $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are similar—and since $\ B^{-1}A^{-1}K_1=I=A^{-1}B^{-1}K_2\ ,$ then $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are invertible.

Conversely, if $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are invertible and similar, then there exists an invertible square matrix $\ Q\ $ such that
$$
K_2=QK_1Q^{-1}\ ,\label{e3}\tag{3}
$$
and if we put $\ A\ed K_1Q^{-1}\ ,$$\ B\ed Q\ ,$ then $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ satisfy equations (\ref{e1}) and (\ref{e2}) and are invertible.

You can determine whether $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are similar by reducing them both to [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) .  While a matrix doesn't usually have a *unique* Jordan normal form, all of them must contain the same set of [Jordan blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix). If $\ J_1\ $ and $\ J_2\ $ are Jordan normal forms for $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ ,$ respectively, then $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are similar if and only if there's a permutation matrix $\ P\ $ such that
$$
J_2=PJ_1P^{-1}\label{e4}\tag{4}\ .
$$
Whether or not this is the case can always be seen easily by inspection (provided $\ J_1\ $ and $\ J_2\ $ are not too large).  The matrices  $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ are related to their Jordan forms by equations

\begin{align}
J_1&=Q_1^{-1}K_1Q_1\ \ \text{and}\\
J_2&=Q_2^{-1}K_2Q_2\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ Q_1\ $ and $\ Q_2\ $ are matrices whose columns form a complete set of [generalised eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) of $\ K_1\ $ and $\ K_2\ $ respectively. If equation (\ref{e4}) holds, then
\begin{align}
K_2&=Q_2J_2Q_2^{-1}\\
&=Q_2PJ_1P^{-1}Q_2^{-1}\\
&=Q_2PQ_1^{-1}K_1Q_1P^{-1}Q_2^{-1}\\
&=Q_2PQ_1^{-1}K_1\big(Q_2PQ_1^{-1}\big)^{-1}\ ,
\end{align}
so equation (\ref{e3}) holds with $\ Q=Q_2PQ_1^{-1}\ .$ Therefore, a solution of equations (\ref{e1}) and (\ref{e2}) is given by $\ A\ed K_1(Q_2PQ_1^{-1}\big)^{-1}\ ,$$\ B\ed Q_2PQ_1^{-1}\ .$

**Example**

Since your matrices $\ AB\ $ and $\ BA\ $ aren't invertible it's impossible for $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ to be both invertible.  Nevertheless, it's still possible to perform the above procedure to find two matrices $\ A_0\ $ and $\ B_0\ $ such that
\begin{align}
A_0B_0&=AB=\pmatrix{4 & -4 &  -1 \\ 
5 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-5 & -1 & -1 }\ \ \text{, and}\label{e5}\tag{5}\\
B_0A_0&=BA=\pmatrix{5 & 4 &  1 \\ 
-4 & 1 & -5 \\ 
-1 & 1 & -2}\ .\label{e6}\tag{6}
\end{align}
As several commenters on your question have pointed out, you can't expect the solution of the above equations to be unique, so if you hadn't told us the values of the $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ you used to generate the matrices $\ AB\ $ and $\ BA\ $ there would be no way of telling which of the many solutions $\ A_0,B_0\ $ of equations (\ref{e5}) and (\ref{e6}) would correspond to them. As it happens, both matrices $\ AB\ $ and $\ BA\ $ have the same $3$ distinct eigenvalues $\ 2+i\sqrt{11}, 2-i\sqrt{11}, $ and $\ 0\ ,$ and are therefore diagonalisable with the same Jordan normal form
$$
J=\pmatrix{2+i\sqrt{11}&0&0\\0&2-i\sqrt{11}&0\\0&0&0}\ .
$$
We can therefore (and, in fact, *must*) take $\ P\ $ to be the identity in equation (\ref{e4}) above. The eigenvectors of the matrices $\ AB\ $ and $\ BA\ $ give us the matrices
$$
Q_1=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\\frac{2}{3}-\frac{i\sqrt{11}}{3}&\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i\sqrt{11}}{3}&3\\
-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{i\sqrt{11}}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{i\sqrt{11}}{3}&-8}
$$
and
$$
Q_2=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\-\frac{22}{31}+\frac{7i\sqrt{11}}{31}&-\frac{22}{31}-\frac{7i\sqrt{11}}{31}&-1\\
-\frac{5}{31}+\frac{3i\sqrt{11}}{31}&-\frac{5}{31}-\frac{3i\sqrt{11}}{31}&-1}
$$
for which
\begin{align}
J&=Q_1^{-1}ABQ_1\\
&=Q_2^{-1}BAQ_2\ ,
\end{align}
and the procedure described above then gives us
\begin{align}
A_0&=ABQ_1Q_2^{-1}=\pmatrix{5&4&1\\4&-3&7\\-4&3&-7}\\
B_0&=Q_2Q_1^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\-\frac{8}{31}&-\frac{29}{31}&-\frac{8}{31}\\
\frac{1}{31}&-\frac{8}{31}&\frac{1}{31}}
\end{align}
as a solution to equations (\ref{e5}) and (\ref{e6}), which can be verified by direct multiplication:
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{5&4&1\\4&-3&7\\-4&3&-7}\pmatrix{1&0&0\\-\frac{8}{31}&-\frac{29}{31}&-\frac{8}{31}\\
\frac{1}{31}&-\frac{8}{31}&\frac{1}{31}}&=\pmatrix{4 & -4 &  -1 \\ 
5 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-5 & -1 & -1 }\\
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\-\frac{8}{31}&-\frac{29}{31}&-\frac{8}{31}\\
\frac{1}{31}&-\frac{8}{31}&\frac{1}{31}}\pmatrix{5&4&1\\4&-3&7\\-4&3&-7}&=\pmatrix{5 & 4 &  1 \\ 
-4 & 1 & -5 \\ 
-1 & 1 & -2}\ .
\end{align}
Note that while $\ B_0\ $ is invertible, $\ A_0\ $ isn't.